# OpenCV warpAffine with rotation with respect to arbitrary point

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-rotation, affinetransform

I'm using OpenCV in C++. I have two images of faces, and I'm trying to align the faces to each other. I have features denoting the eyes, nose, and other points of interest in the faces. I use Arun's method to extract a rotation, translation, and scale that translates the centroid of the feature sets in one image to the other. Then, it rotates and scales it. And I'm trying to use this transformation to warp one image so that the face in the image aligns with the face in the other image. At least that's the idea, but I'm having problems. It seems that the rotation and translation are being performed in a different order than I expected in warpAffine. There also seems to be an issue with row/column ordering versus x/y coordinates. Also, as the title suggests, I think the warpAffine is doing the operations with respect to 0,0 in the image whereas I expect them to be done around the centroid of the face points. What should I be doing to correctly align these two sets of points? Here's my code:

```
// R is the rotation as computed by Arun's method
// centered_moving is the moving points with the centroid subtracted from them
// same with centered_base
for (int i = 0; i < base.cols; i++)
{
    a = centered_base.col(i);
    b = centered_moving.col(i).t();
    H += a*b;
}
SVD sv;
Mat W, U, Vt;
sv.compute(H, W, U, Vt);
Mat R = (Vt.t())*(U.t());
// centroid_moving and centroid_base are the centroids of the two point clouds, moving is the cloud that will be translated
Mat trans = -centroid_moving + centroid_base;
Mat Afmat = Mat::zeros(2, 3, ddepth);
Mat tmpmat = Afmat(Rect(0, 0, 2, 2));
R = Mat::eye(2, 2, ddepth);
R.copyTo(tmpmat);
Afmat.at<double>(1, 2) = trans.at<double>(0);
Afmat.at<double>(0, 2) = trans.at<double>(1);
warpAffine(image_moving, affine_result, Afmat, image_moving.size());
```

Comment: Can't you use [getAffineTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#getaffinetransform) with the two vector of points? Or [findHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?#findhomography)?

Comment: I tried findHomography, but it results in very warped registrations, for some reason.
getAffineTransform can only gain information from 3 points, and my matches are imperfect so 3 points isn't good enough. I have about 30 points.

Comment: Are you sure that the order of the points is the same for the two vectors you pass to findHomography? CV_RANSAC should give you robust results.

Comment: Actually, Homography wasn't working but I solved it with getAffineTransform. The problem was that my points were in row,column order whereas the algorithms seems to want in x,y order. Solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using points in row,column order whereas warpAffine wants a matrix derived from points in x,y order (aka column,row). Flipping the points and using getAffineTransform solved the issue.